# Nested Update Panel Issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have two nested UpdatePanle and a button and an editor in parent panel and a GridView in child panel.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btn_UsersList" runat="server" 
            OnClick="btn_UsersList_Click" Text="users" />
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:GridView ID="GridView_UsersList" runat="server">
                </asp:GridView>
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btn_UsersList" 
                    EventName="Click" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        <fckeditorv2:fckeditor id="FCKeditor_Message" runat="server" 
            basepath="~/fckeditor/"></fckeditorv2:fckeditor>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I'd like to update the child panel when click button but don't update the parent UpdatePanel.How Can I do this ? what is the problem of my code?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Set `ChildrenAsTriggers="false"`, and then within each individual `UpdatePanel`
use the `<triggers>` tag (I usually place it right below my
`ContentTemplate`) to manually specify which controls an update panel
updates on. I almost always use this so I know what is causing my
postbacks and I don't have something I'm not aware of going on.

Example:

```
<UpdatePanel id="Parent" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" UpdateMode="conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <UpdatePanel id="Child" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" UpdateMode="conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <!-- Content Here -->
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <!-- Updates only the child panel -->
                <asp:AsynchronousPostBackTrigger 
                     ControlID="btnChangeChildPanel" EventName="Click" />
             </Triggers>
        </UpdatePanel>
        <asp:Button id="btnChangeChildPanel" runat="server"
            OnClick="btnChangeChildPanel_OnClick" />
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <!-- Add parent triggers here -->
    </Triggers>
</UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

@sohren

You probably need to unblock the UI at some point. You can use the `pageLoad()` function for that purpose. If your AJAX request ran successfully after blocking the UI, the `pageLoad()` function will be called when the response is received and the page is updated. This is where you can unblock the UI.

Comment: ??? unblock the UI? What are you talking about? The issue is he's using a nested update panel and not specifiying which of the panels is the parent vs the child. Hence as per the answer above, you need to specifically set the ChildrenAsTrigger to false.